# Performing update operations on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Hadoop** is not designed to do updates. I tried with `hive` it has to do insert overwrite which is a costly operation also we can do some work around using Map reduce which again is a costly operation.

Is their any other tool or way by which i can do `frequent updates on Hadoop` or can i use `spark` for the same. Please help me i am not getting enough information about this even after googling 100 times. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update realtime on Hadoop,  **Hbase** is the solution you might want to take a look at, Hive is  not meant for random/frequent updates its more of a Data crunching tool not a replacement of RDBMS

Comment: Thanks novice but sorry i forgot to mention that it's a transactional data which require joins and other costly operation which is not best suited for NoSQL.